# Create multiple lagged variables using a zoo object

Tags: r

I need to create 'n' number of variables with lags of the original variable from 1 to 'n' on the fly. Something like so :-
OrigVar

```
DatePeriod, value
2/01/2018,6
3/01/2018,4
4/01/2018,0
5/01/2018,2
6/01/2018,4
7/01/2018,1
8/01/2018,6
9/01/2018,2
10/01/2018,7

Lagged 1 variable
2/01/2018,NA
3/01/2018,6
4/01/2018,4
5/01/2018,0
6/01/2018,2
7/01/2018,4
8/01/2018,1
9/01/2018,6
10/01/2018,2
11/01/2018,7

Lagged 2 variable
2/01/2018,NA
3/01/2018,NA
4/01/2018,6
5/01/2018,4
6/01/2018,0
7/01/2018,2
8/01/2018,4
9/01/2018,1
10/01/2018,6
11/01/2018,2
12/01/2018,7

Lagged 3 variable
2/01/2018,NA
3/01/2018,NA
4/01/2018,NA
5/01/2018,6
6/01/2018,4
7/01/2018,0
8/01/2018,2
9/01/2018,4
10/01/2018,1
11/01/2018,6
12/01/2018,2
13/01/2018,7
```

and so on

I tried using the shift function and various other functions. Wtih most of them that worked for me, the lagged variables finished at the last date of the original variable. In other words, the length of the lagged variable is the same as that of the original variable.

What I am looking for the new lagged variable to be shifted down by the 'kth' lag and the data series to be extended by 'k' elements including the index.

The reason I need this is to be able to compute the value of the dependent variable using the regression coeffficients and the corresponding lagged variable value beyond the in-sample period

```
y1 <- Lag(ciresL1_usage_1601_1612, shift = 1)
head(y1)
2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05 2016-01-06 2016-01-07 
        NA  -5171.051  -6079.887  -3687.227  -3229.453  -2110.368 

y2 <- Lag(ciresL1_usage_1601_1612, shift = 2)
head(y2)
2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05 2016-01-06 2016-01-07 
        NA         NA  -5171.051  -6079.887  -3687.227  -3229.453 
tail(y2)
2016-12-26 2016-12-27 2016-12-28 2016-12-29 2016-12-30 2016-12-31 
 -2316.039  -2671.185  -4100.793  -2043.020  -1147.798   1111.674 

tail(ciresL1_usage_1601_1612)
2016-12-26 2016-12-27 2016-12-28 2016-12-29 2016-12-30 2016-12-31 
 -4100.793  -2043.020  -1147.798   1111.674   3498.729   2438.739
```

Is there a way to do it relatively easily. I know I can do it by looping and adding 'k' rows in a new vector and reloading the data in to this new vector appropriately shifting the data values in the new vector but I don't want to use that method unless I have to. I am quietly confident that there has to be a better way to do it than this!

By the way, the object is a zoo object with daily dates as the index.

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the input zoo object to zooreg and then use `lag.zooreg` like this:

```
library(zoo)

# test input
z <- zoo(1:10, as.Date("2008-01-01") + 0:9)

zr <- as.zooreg(z)
lag(zr, -(0:3))
```

giving:

```
           lag0 lag-1 lag-2 lag-3
2008-01-01    1    NA    NA    NA
2008-01-02    2     1    NA    NA
2008-01-03    3     2     1    NA
2008-01-04    4     3     2     1
2008-01-05    5     4     3     2
2008-01-06    6     5     4     3
2008-01-07    7     6     5     4
2008-01-08    8     7     6     5
2008-01-09    9     8     7     6
2008-01-10   10     9     8     7
2008-01-11   NA    10     9     8
2008-01-12   NA    NA    10     9
2008-01-13   NA    NA    NA    10
```

Comment: Why do I get this error <- Error: `n` must be a nonnegative integer scalar, not integer of length 4. <- What package do I need for it to work?

Comment: You may have conflicting packages loaded.  Restart a fresh R session (be sure that .Rdata is not loaded) and enter the code in the answer.

Comment: HI <- One more question - why did you have to convert it to a zooreg object from zoo object?

Comment: zoo objects are completely irregular whereas zooreg objects are zoo objects with an underlying regularity and that regularity can be used by lag.zooreg to extend the series.   With lag.zoo the series cannot be extended.

Comment: Hi >- I find that this code "lag(as.zooreg(ciresL1_usage_1610_1703), -(0:7))" does not work with "tidyverse" or "dplyr". With both of those detached, it works. My understanding is that both of the above packages make data manipulations much better and faster, then why does this not work with the better packages? Is "detaching them, run the above command and then reattaching them" the only work around for it or is there a better solution available?

Comment: The tidyverse packages don't work well with other packages.  For example, they redefine lag and filter in ways which conflict with base R whereas zoo respects the way R works.  Also it is not true that they are, in general, faster although, of course, they may be in certain instances. In some cases they are substantially slower.   To address any conflicts either change the order of your library statements or use explicit qualification, e.g. `dplyr::mutate` so that `library(dplyr)` is not needed.  You can still get pipes by using `library(magrittr)` since it does not conflict as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks mate! Good to know! Greatly appreciated. Regards.